# How to use hostip.info service in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a method named getIP() which returns the clients ip as a string.

How do I use this IP to get the location of the client using [this](http://www.hostip.info/use.html) service.

This is how i show the clients IP address.

```
string IP = getIP();
lblIPAddress.Text = "IP " + IP;
```

How do i include the clients location in ?

```
i.e. lblIPAddress.Text = "IP " + IP+ "location" ;)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below you can find a very simple snippet which I was using to get data from XML endpoint of that API some time ago (I believe there was no changes to the API so it still should work):

```
string city;
string country;
string countryCode;
decimal longitude;
decimal latitude;

XmlTextReader hostIPInfoReader = new XmlTextReader("http://api.hostip.info/?ip=" + IP);
while (hostIPInfoReader.Read()) {
    if (hostIPInfoReader.IsStartElement()) {
        if (hostIPInfoReader.Name == "gml:name")
            city = hostIPInfoReader.ReadString();

        if (hostIPInfoReader.Name == "countryName")
            country = hostIPInfoReader.ReadString();

        if (hostIPInfoReader.Name == "countryAbbrev")
            countryCode = hostIPInfoReader.ReadString();

        if (hostIPInfoReader.Name == "gml:coordinates") {
            string[] coordinates = hostIPInfoReader.ReadString().Split(new char[] { ',' });
            longitude = decimal.Parse(coordinates[0]);
            latitude = decimal.Parse(coordinates[1]);
        }
    }
}
```

This code can be of course improved but I believe it`s a good starting point for you.